# Type a manual range into a single cell, specifically for the IRR function in Excel

Tags: excel

To use the IRR function, it requires a range of values. I have a list of values, but for reasons outside of this I cannot enter the values into any cells. I want to manually enter the range into the formula.

It expect to see =IRR(A1:A5)
I want to enter =IRR(-500,100,200,250,300) but the commas make it think I am trying to enter different parts of the function. Any idea how to create my own range without using cells to do it? Prefer to stay away from VBA as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRR takes an array:

```
=IRR({-500,100,200,250,300})
```

[image]

---

If the number series `-500,100,200,250,300` is found in one cell then you will need to create the array with the following formula:

```
=IRR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)))
```

[image]

Comment: An Array!! Thank you!!

Comment: Please consider marking correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.